# Setting up a cron job with Laravel and AWS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, aws-lambda

I have a list of customers' email and I would like to send promos and news every week.

How do I set this up on AWS using Laravel?

What I currently did was using Laravel's queues something like this:

```
website.com/api/SendScheduledEmail
```

So far what I have tried is the crontab on Linux but I don't know how can I visit and execute my URL using it.

Comment: Cron jobs are not triggered using a URL. They are run by your server and do not require a URL endpoint. You should look into the basics of cron jobs and how to set them up on your server. Are you using an EC2 server, and is that what you mean by AWS?

Comment: Yes we're using EC2. What I would like to do is to send email to our customers every week. Would that be available if done using laravel? Thank you by the way for pointing out it's not triggered by URL.

Comment: Yes, it's simple. There are two things that you need to do in order to get this work. You need to create a cron job Command in Laravel. These commands are stored in the app/console/commands directory. These are triggered by the kernel schedule, which is located at app/console/kernel.php. The kernel says "run X command every day at X time".  The other step is to set up a daemon to run on your server to check your kernel every minute. This whole process is detailed here: https://scotch.io/@Kidalikevin/how-to-set-up-cron-job-in-laravel

Answer (score 1):

you can do as per what @eResourcesInc mentioned whereby you add a scheduled command shown below

```
 $schedule->command('command:send_newsletter')
            ->daily()
            ->appendOutputTo(storage_path('logs/send_newsletter.log'));
```

Documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/artisan

If your task has the potential to take a long time/or consume alot of resources. Maybe you can try serverless, like running your task as a function in AWS or Aliyun. More info here: https://vapor.laravel.com

Hope it helps.